# chrome-extension has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cors, fetch

I checked on many answers to similar questions, but none of them helped me to fix the issue.

I'm converting my manifest v2 extension to v3.
This is my background.js code to get data.

```
let url='[my url]';
let params  ="test=1"; 

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", url);
headers.append('Content-Type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: headers,
  body: params,
})
.then(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
}
.catch(err => console.log(err)));
```

**Note:** The backend code is configured correctly for CORS, and is already working for manifest V2 extension using **XMLHttpRequest** approach with the same headers and data, but XMLHttpRequest is not supported in manifest v3.

The error I get is,

```
Access to fetch at '[my url]' (redirected from '[my url]') from origin 
'chrome-extension://xxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Can anyone please notice what I have done wrong or missing using the fetch with headers?

Comment: You can't set CORS headers in `fetch`, it's the server's job. Did you already add the site to your manifest.json in host_permissions?

Comment: @wOxxOm, Yes I already included "host_permissions":[ "http://[my url]"] in manifest.json. If it's not possible to include headers what's the correct way to post and get results using manifest v3 with headers?

Comment: `http` should be `https`.

Comment: @wOxxOm my URL is not https, it's http. and the backend is already configured for CORS and my old manifest version 2 extension is working fine up to date for the same backend using XMLHttpRequest as I mentioned in my question.